# Send email on commit to SVN

Tags: svn, post-commit

How to configure Subversion to send email to all developers and administrators when I commit source code?

Answer (score 2):

If you have admin access to the SVN server, you can use the post-commit hook of SVN as described in http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html. For sending the mail, you could use the mailx command on a Unix machine.

Comment: Thanks Mr fschmitt
But I use window , in folder hook don't have file commit-email.pl ,I downed load them and put into hook folder , but it not run 
I down load at this link :

"http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/"

and use guide

"http://www.andywu.co.uk/subversion_commit_emails.htm"

I configed this:

commit-email.pl "$REPOS" "$REV" --from levanduy@iritech.com  -s "svn commit:" levanduy@iritech.com
log-commit.py --repository "$REPOS" --revision "$REV"

But When I commit file , It is ok but it not send email 
Please hep me!!

Comment: Do you have perl installed correctly? Otherwise the script can not run. Look here if not: http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads

Comment: Ok I install perl? It commit ok but not send email. !

Comment: I don't know what is happen with config!